# NavigationControlller Push and Pop in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I am using the UINavigationControl based application, I am pushing view one by one. Some times i need to push the same view again.In this scenario whether i have to find the view and pop or can create new view and push. which is the best method? whether any standard method handle this situation. When pushed view release from memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on the experience you want your users to have.  If a user navigates from A -> B -> C ->D **-> B**   and the user presses the back button, does the user expect to see A or D?

In my experience, the user expects to see D, hence, you should not move the user "back in the stack" when they think they are moving forward in the stack (from D to B).

Answer:  new view controller.